# how can i find my .net frame work version

Tags: asp.net

how can i find the version of my .net frame work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in the web.config

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to check it programmatically:

```
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registryKey;

        registryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\", false );

        string[] installedNetVersions = registryKey.GetSubKeyNames();
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Environment.Version` will give you the CLR version your application is running under - this may not be the same as the ASP.NET version.